# How to automatically advance a slide after a video is done playing in PowerPoint for Mac

Tags: macos, powerpoint

I would like to automatically advance a slide in PowerPoint for Mac after a video on that slide is done playing. This seems to be possible in PowerPoint for Windows but not for Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a Mac user:
here is? if it helps you...
You will need to set the SLIDESHOW (tab) to Use (Rehearsal) Timings. This will automatically advance the slide after the last animation action. You could, of course give it some seconds to wait, but it sounds like you just want to advance the slide.